# C#: best way to create topic subscriptions

Tags: c#, servicebus, azureservicebus

My application creates some subscriptions (~30) on Service Bus for the same number of topics.
It is a client application and I'm creating unique names for subscriptions to ensure that each application instance received all messages.
Being a client app, startup time is very important, and I've noticed that it's taking much time to create the subscriptions, thinking that maybe I'm not using the best option.

I'm creating subscription clients from a namespace manager because I also need filters on this subscriptions:

```
namespaceManager.CreateSubscriptionAsync("topic", "uniqueSubscriptionName", new SqlFilter("my rule"));
```

ServiceBus guidelines suggest using a shared MessagingFactory to create objects, but I see two problems for MessagingFactory.CreateSubscriptionClient:

- I can't specify a filter when creating subscriptions
- it is not async

Which is the most efficient way to create those subscriptions including their filters?
Remark: I'm using Windows Azure SDK 2.1.4 because the application must be compatible with both Azure ServiceBus and Windows Server ServiceBus

Comment: Can you provide clarifying details? How much time is it taking? How much do you want it to take? What are the subscriptions used for? Why are you using a topic?  Etc. Barring someone who knows the precise answer to the question you asked off the top of their head, we might lead you down a slightly different path given your requirements.

Comment: Any tips how to create a subscription without the Manage right? I am creating a client-server application and the clients have to have Manage right to be allowed to create a subscription. They should rather only have the Listen right.